# Adding info to Highcharts tooltip besides axis values

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm going to use the example of a crane load chart to explain what I'm needing. Let's say I have a highchart with lifting radius in feet along the X axis, and lifting capacity in lbs on the Y axis. Of course I want these two to show up in my tooltip, but I'd also like additional information as well. For example, main boom angle and tip height. As a crane reaches farther out, the lifting capacity goes down, and so does the tip height / main boom angle. I'd like to have a tooltip that reads as follows:

YYY,YYY lbs capacity @ XX' radius
ZZZ tip height, WW deg. main boom angle.

As I stated, the lbs capacity would be from the Y axis and the radius from the X axis, but the other two values would be extra information not shown on any axis. Is it possible to produce a tooltip that pulls extra information not shown on any axis?

Comment: You should put the code you've tried on a jsfiddle so far, you'll get more people to help you.

Comment: Good point. This project is still way in the preliminary phase so I haven't written any code yet. I've just used Highcharts on other projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can call other javascript functions from within the formatter function for the tooltip.  In the following example getTipHeight and getBoomAngle are functions you would define outside of the highcharts constructor to return the ZZZ and WW values for you. I'm not exactly sure how you would decide the appropriate tip height or boom angle, but I'm assuming you could figure them out by passing this.point.x and/or this.point.y into the two functions.

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.point.y+ ' lbs capacity @ ' + this.point.x + '\' radius <br/>' + getTipHeight(this.point.x,this.point.y) + ' tip height, ' + getBoomAngle(this.point.x,this.point.y) + 'deg. main boom angle.';
            }
        },
```